# What is model in EF Core context class?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

The class `DbContext` has a virtual method `OnModelCreating` that one should override when wanting to change **the model** it creates.
Throughout the tutorials i came across the term **Model** many times, without knowing what it really is?
Is it the same Model as in **EDM**? or part of it?

Comment: What did Google searches give you?

Comment: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your Model is your POCO class (or DTO). You will see many different names for the same thing.

But it's a Model example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EDM files are responsible for the *mapping* your Model to the database.

Remember that 3 differents way to work with EF. You have Code First, Database First and Designer First. The concept of EDM can get a little difference between them.

My answer is not complete about the theme, it's just a 'mindset' for you.